# PHP update() function not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web-applications

I am developing a web application and need to update database entries as per user requirements via forms. I am using the Savant templating engine for the MVC structure. All was going fine till I went on to test the `update()` function. When I filled the update form and clicked the update button, it led to a blank screen with the URL of update.php. Here's the code of the Update.php page:

```
<?php
    include_once("../../Resources/Libraries/Savant3.php");
    include_once("../../Classes/Models/Test.php");
    $s=new Savant3();
    $s->method=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET")
    {
        $b=Test::readSingle($_GET['id']);
        $s->b=$b;
        $s->display("UpdateView.tpl");
    }
    else
    {
        $b=new Test();
        $b->id= $_POST['id'];
        $b->title= $_POST['title'];
        $b->address= $_POST['address'];
        $b->location= $_POST['location'];
        if($b->validate==true)
        {
            Test::update($b);
            header('location: ../../Applications/Success');
            return;
        }
    }
?>
```

I think that the problem is, most probably, somewhere in the above code. In case you wish to see the `update()` function in the model, here it is:

```
public static function update(Test $b)
{
    $id=$b->id;
    $title=strip_tags($b->title);
    $address=strip_tags($b->address);
    $location=strip_tags($b->location);
    $m=new mysqli("localhost", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX");
    $s=$m->prepare("update test set title=?, post=?, location=? where id=?");
    $s->bind_param("sssi", $title, $address, $location, $id);
    $s->execute();
}
```

Please help in case you have any information. This is important! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What does your server's error log say?

Comment: @ceejayoz There is no error. It just ends up in a blank page.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true)` to the top of Update.php, blank page is usually a sign of an error, but server config maybe set not to display them

Comment: A blank page is usually an indication that there's a server error. You could also comment out lines and reenable them one by one to see what's causing issues.

Comment: @ikartik90: `public static function update(Test $b)` -- that `Test` looks suspect.

Comment: @German Rumm Thanks buddy. It was just a missing pair of parentheses after the validate function. Thanks a lot. It worked. Cheers! :)

Comment: @stealthyninja That's just type hinting - in PHP it is valid if the hint is an object.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I specified under the comments under the question, I got my problem solved as I realized that I was missing a pair of parenthesis after the `validate()` function. Cheers.